# NFS permission denied with sec=krb5p

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, kerberos

I'm setting up NFSv4.2 with MIT Kerberos (`sec=krb5p`) on two Hyper-V VMs running Debian 11 (Bullseye). When I use machine-based authentication (`sec=sys`), everything works fine. With Kerberos (`sec=krb5p`), I'm able to mount the share on the client, but I see `Permission denied` when I try to access the share. I've documented all of this in detail below, including all relevant configuration info that came to mind. I'm a bit out of my depth. What am I missing or doing wrong?

### NFS works with `sec=sys`

/etc/exports on the server:

```
/exports/ned 192.168.1.0/24(sec=sys,rw,no_subtree_check)
```

/etc/fstab on the client:

```
test-debian-server:/exports/ned /imports/ned nfs sec=sys 0 0
```

Testing the share:

```
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ su - -c "nfsstat -m"
Password:
/imports/ned from test-debian-server:/exports/ned
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.63,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.62

ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ id
uid=2001(ned) gid=2001(ned) groups=2001(ned)
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned ned 4096 Jan 26 17:57 ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ cd ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports/ned$ ls
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports/ned$ touch test.txt
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports/ned$ ls
test.txt
```

Verifying test.txt on the server:

```
ned@test-debian-server:/exports$ id
uid=2001(ned) gid=2001(ned) groups=2001(ned)
ned@test-debian-server:/exports$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned ned 4096 Jan 26 19:11 ned
ned@test-debian-server:/exports$ ls -l ned
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ned ned 0 Jan 26 19:11 test.txt
```

### Permission denied with `sec=krb5p`

**Server configuration**

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       test-debian-server.test test-debian-server
192.168.1.63    test-debian-desktop
192.168.1.62    test-debian-server
```

/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server:

```
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
NEED_SVCGSSD=""
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=""
```

/etc/default/nfs-common:

```
NEED_STATD=
STATDOPTS=
NEED_IDMAPD=
NEED_GSSD=
```

/etc/exports:

```
/exports/ned 192.168.1.0/24(sec=krb5p,rw,no_subtree_check)
```

/etc/krb5.conf (heavily abridged):

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = TEST

        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true

[realms]
        TEST = {
                kdc = test-debian-server
                admin_server = test-debian-server
        }
```

Kerberos principals:

```
root@test-debian-server:~# kadmin.local listprincs
K/M@TEST
host/test-debian-desktop@TEST
host/test-debian-server@TEST
kadmin/admin@TEST
kadmin/changepw@TEST
kadmin/test-debian-server@TEST
kiprop/test-debian-server@TEST
krbtgt/TEST@TEST
nfs/test-debian-desktop@TEST
nfs/test-debian-server@TEST
```

Kerberos keytab:

```
root@test-debian-server:~# klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 nfs/test-debian-server@TEST (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 nfs/test-debian-server@TEST (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 host/test-debian-server@TEST (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 host/test-debian-server@TEST (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

NFS effective domain:

```
root@test-debian-server:~# nfsidmap -d
test
```

Permissions on exports:

```
root@test-debian-server:~# ls -ld /exports /exports/*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 26 17:58 /exports
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned  ned  4096 Jan 26 19:11 /exports/ned
```

**Client configuration**

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       test-debian-desktop.test        test-debian-desktop
192.168.1.63    test-debian-desktop
192.168.1.62    test-debian-server
```

/etc/default/nfs-common: same as server.

/etc/fstab:

```
test-debian-server:/exports/ned /imports/ned nfs sec=krb5p 0 0
```

/etc/krb5.conf: same as server.

Kerberos keytab:

```
root@test-debian-desktop:~# klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 nfs/test-debian-desktop@TEST (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 nfs/test-debian-desktop@TEST (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 host/test-debian-desktop@TEST (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 host/test-debian-desktop@TEST (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

NFS effective domain:

```
root@test-debian-desktop:~# nfsidmap -d
test
```

Permissions on imports (after unmounting share):

```
root@test-debian-desktop:~# umount /imports/ned
root@test-debian-desktop:~# ls -ld /imports /imports/*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 26 19:08 /imports
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 26 17:02 /imports/ned
```

(Note: I get the same result when I `chown ned:ned /imports/ned`. I think `root:root` is correct, to prevent `ned` from accidentally writing to the local disk if the mount fails?)

**Permission denied**

After rebooting server and client:

```
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ su -c "nfsstat -m"
Password:
/imports/ned from test-debian-server:/exports/ned
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5p,clientaddr=192.168.1.63,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.62

ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned ned 4096 Jan 26 19:11 ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ cd ned
bash: cd: ned: Permission denied
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$
```

Sometimes `ned` can list the share with `ls -l` initially but can't `cd` into it, as in the session above; a minute later, if `ned` tries to `ls -l`, they will see `Permission denied` and question marks for the `ned` folder's attributes. When this happens, I can do the following:

```
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'ned': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ su -c "ls -l /imports"
Password:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned ned 4096 Jan 26 19:11 ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ned ned 4096 Jan 26 19:11 ned
ned@test-debian-desktop:/imports$
```

This appears to be due to attribute cache expiration: if I disable the attribute cache with `noac` in /etc/fstab on the client and remount, `ned` reliably sees `Permission denied` and question marks when calling `ls -l`.

### What I've tried

On both client and server, I have:

- Set `Verbosity = 4` in `/etc/idmapd.conf`
- Used `rpcdebug` to set all flags for `nfs`, `nfsd`, `nlm`, and `rpc`
- Scoured the systemd journal for relevant information (after rebooting and attempting to access the share).

I have checked `systemctl status` to verify that the following units are `active`, and I have read through the recent journal entries listed for each (and found no obvious indicators of what's wrong):

- Server:

  - krb5-admin-server
  - krb5-kdc
  - nfs-kernel-server
  - nfs-idmapd
  - nfs-mountd
  - nfs-server
  - rpc-svcgssd
  - rpc-gssd
- Client:

  - rpc-gssd
  - imports-ned.mount

As far as I can tell, Kerberos is authenticating correctly.

I've read through every relevant manpage and online manual I can find and every question on StackExchange that appeared to be related, and I haven't been able to fix the issue or get either client or server to generate an error message to tell me why permission is being denied.

Edited to add `host/test-debian-desktop` and `host/test-debian-server` Kerberos principals and keys in accordance with [Unix Application Servers - MIT Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install_appl_srv.html)

### What I was missing

The chosen answer does a good job of explaining the reason my configuration wasn't working. In case anyone is in the same situation, here are the details of what I was missing - and please read the answer below for why.

Kerberos authenticates individual users (which for some reason I thought it didn't). So for `ned` to connect, Kerberos must have a `ned@TEST` principal, and the Linux user `ned` on the client PC must `kinit` to get a Ticket-Granting Ticket (TGT) for this principal. Then everything works beautifully. To more or less automate this, I did the following:

/etc/krb5/user/<uid>/client.keytab: holds keys for `ned` and is **only readable by ned!** I used `0600` permissions, with owner and group both as `ned`.

With this keytab, I can simply invoke `kinit -ki` to log in without needing to enter a password. The quick-and-dirty way I automated this was to add it to ~/.gnomerc, ~/.bashrc, and ~/.zshrc (since I use Gnome, Bash, and Zsh).

Additionally, since I deploy these configurations via Ansible and have some systems that share dotfiles but don't need NFS access, I got a bit fancier with Bash and Zsh, only running `kinit` if it and the client keytab are present:

~/.bashrc:

```
# Grab or renew a Kerberos ticket.
if type -t kinit >/dev/null && [[ -r /etc/krb/user/$(id -u)/client.keytab ]]
then
  kinit -ki
fi
```

~/.zshrc:

```
# Grab or renew a Kerberos ticket.
if type kinit >/dev/null && [[ -r /etc/krb/user/$(id -u)/client.keytab ]]
then
  kinit -ki
fi
```

Comment: Can you please copy here the value of `klist` command, without any flags?

Comment: You definitely found the problem. I had no credentials cache, i.e. no tickets, on client. When I add ned@TEST to Kerberos and kinit on Ned, I can access the share correctly. I'm not sure if I should add this to my client's keytab or what exactly is the right way to set it up; if you let me know in an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got "permission denied" was because you didn't have a Kerberos TGT (ticket-granting-ticket) in your credentials cache, as you could see in the output of `klist`. You had to run `kinit` for the account and type your password. Once you authenticated and got a TGT ticket cached, you could use this ticket to authenticate to the NFS server.

You need to remember that the whole idea of Kerberos authentication is that you need to "prove" your identity to the NFS server (or any other service for that matter). You "prove" it by presenting your cached TGT that you generated by typing your password (that only you know) to the `kinit` command. So usually that's the way it's supposed to work. You can change the expiration and renew times in your `krb5`/`sssd`/whatever to make your tickets last longer before expiring, but eventually at some point you'll need to re-authenticate one way or the other.

Of course you could always create a keytab for your account. Don't add it to the client's keytab! The client keytab is for the **client** alone. You will need to create new keytab in a new file for **your** account and keep this file secure and private with minimum permissions, and use this keytab to generate the TGT in your credential cache without typing a password interactively. Theoretically you can even create a `crontab` that will do it for you periodically, but that's less secure, as someone could steal your keytab at some point (if he has root access, for instance) and pretend to be you for other services, but that's for your consideration.

Also, if you're going down the keytab road, don't forget that any time you change the account's password, you'll also need to update your keytab.